# Separating the int values based on the occurrance of sequence of the values in java?

Tags: java, int

i have an integer values as:
1299129912

i want to store it as 
12
12
12 
in the int v1,v2,v3;
i.e.,when ever 9909 occurs we need to separate the values individually. Is it possible in java. If so please anyone help me.

here is the code I'm trying

```
    int l = 1299129912;

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("99");

    Matcher m1 = p.matcher(l);       
   if (m1.matches()) {
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
The method matcher(CharSequence) in the type Pattern is not applicable for the arguments (int)
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: int l = 1299129912;
        
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("99");
        
        Matcher m1 = p.matcher(l);        if (m1.matches()) {
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
    The method matcher(CharSequence) in the type Pattern is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: Before editing your post, you were splitting the number on `9909`, now you changed it to `99`, but still have `9909` in your question. Can you make up your mind please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very possible in java. Just convert the integer to a string and replace the 9909 with a space.

Example:

```
String s="1234990912349909";
s=s.replaceAll("9909","");
int a=Integer.parseInt(s);
System.out.println(a);
//output would be 12341234
```

Comment: I want the int value not the String value.

Comment: @SaiDilipReddyKiralam just do Int a=Integer.parseInt(s);

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you already have the value as a `String` since `1234990912349909` is more that `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Then you can `split` the string into `String[]` and do whatever you want with the separate values. E.g. call `parseInt` on each element.

```
String[] values = myIntString.split("9909");
for (String value: values) {
    int v = Integer.parseInt(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you are always going to have 3 integers named v1, v2, and v3 the following would work:

```
String[] numbers = l.toString().split("99");
int v1 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
int v2 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
int v3 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
```

However if you don't know in advance then it might be better to do it like this:

```
String[] numbers = l.toString().split("99");
int[] v = new int[numbers.length];

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    v[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out this is the easiest way to show you how you can resolve your issue:
I included clear comments on every important step. Please check this:

```
    int num = 1239012390;
    // Convert int into a string
    String str = String.valueOf(num);
    // What separates the values
    String toBremoved = "90";
    String str1 = "";
    // Declare a String array to store the final results
    String[] finalStrings = new String[2];
    // i will be used as an index
    int i = 0;
    do {
        // Finds and separates the first value into another string
        finalStrings[i] = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(toBremoved));
        // removes the first number from the original string
        str = str.replaceFirst(finalStrings[i], "");
        // Remove the next separating value
        str = str.replaceFirst(str.substring(str.indexOf(toBremoved), str.indexOf(toBremoved) + toBremoved.length()), "");
        // increments the index
        i++;
    } while (str.indexOf(toBremoved) > 0);  // keeps going for a new iteration if there is still a separating string on the original string

    // Printing the array of strings - just for testing
    System.out.println("String Array:");
    for (String finalString : finalStrings) {
        System.out.println(finalString);
    }

    // If you want to convert the values into ints you can do a standard for loop like this
    // Lets store the results into an int array
    int [] intResults = new int [finalStrings.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < intResults.length; j++) {
        intResults[j] = Integer.valueOf(finalStrings[j]);
    }

    // empty line to separate results
    System.out.println();

    // Printing the array of ints
    System.out.println("int Array:");
    for (int intResult : intResults) {
        System.out.println(intResult);
    }
```

Or in a simplified and more accurate way:
(you can use the example above if you need to understand how it can be done the long way)

```
int num = 1239012390;
String [] numbers = String.valueOf(num).split("90");
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);

System.out.println("1st -> " + num1);
System.out.println("2nd -> " + num2);
```